# Get categories in function in CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, categories

I made a function in the CodeIgniter framework so I can see all my categories of products from my database on a side menu bar but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to echo all the categories.. I used a db_helper.php file to do it.

Some database info:

```
db category table name: categories
I have 2 rows in the categories table:

Row 1 name of categories table: id
Row 2 name of categories table: name
```

This is my db_helper.php file:

```
<?php

function get_categories_h(){
    $CI = get_instance();
    $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
    return $categories;
}
```

This is my Product_model.php file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data)
    {
        {
            $this->db->insert('products', $data);
            $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        return $product_id;
    }



public function get_product_details($product_id) { 
$arrReturn = array(); 
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('products'); 
$this->db->where('product_id', $product_id); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$result = $query->result_array(); 
if(!empty($result)){ 
$arrReturn = $result[0]; 
} 
return $arrReturn; 
}



/*
Get categories
*/

 function get_categories(){
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->db->select('*');
        $ci->db->from('categories');
        $ci->db->get()->result_array();
        return $q;
    }


}

?>

    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('categories'); 
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $result = $query->result_array();
    }
```

And this is the sidebar in a view file where I'm trying to echo all the categories of my database (allecadeaus.php) :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
<div id="categorymenu">
  <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <?php foreach(get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><?php echo $category->name; ?> </a> </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
```

When I try to load the view file I see this error on the sidebar instead of the categories:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 25

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php
Line: 25
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
Line: 12
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

When I print output of get categories:

```
A PHP Error was encountered



Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined variable: q


Filename: models/Product_model.php


Line Number: 42





Backtrace:










            File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/models/Product_model.php

            Line: 42

            Function: _error_handler            








            File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/helpers/db_helper.php

            Line: 6

            Function: get_categories            








            File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php

            Line: 38

            Function: get_categories_h          












            File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php

            Line: 12

            Function: view          












            File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php

            Line: 315

            Function: require_once
```

Comment: You misunderstood the concept of MVC. Please go for codeigniter documentations.

Comment: Why? what i do wrong

Comment: You don't have to return the categories. You have to pass the categories to view.
```$data['categories'] = $this->Product_model->get_categories();
$this->load->view("viewname", $data);```

Comment: Instead of writing the function in helper, I will suggest to write this function in your controller, and call from constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code as following solution.

Please add helper in autoload.php file:

> File Path : application/config/autoload.php

```
<?php 
/*
  | -------------------------------------------------------------------
  |  Auto-load Helper Files
  | -------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Prototype:
  |
  |   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
 */

$autoload['helper'] = array('db_helper');

?>
```

Please change your db_helper.php file:

> File Path : application/helpers/db_helper.php

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

You can check your modal file :

> File Path : application/modal/Product_model.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $product_id;
    }
    public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }
    /*
      Get categories
     */
    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

> You can change your view file.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?>
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Not working sir, still the same error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 25

Comment: you can changes your file inside foreach loop <?php echo $category['name']; ?>

Comment: what do you mean? I already have this: <?php echo $category['name']; ?> in my loop

Comment: can you just print the output of function ```get_categories_h()``` and update the question?

Comment: Please check modal function as per your modal code.

Comment: how do i print that output

Comment: you can add this code in view file. `<?php  echo "<pre>"; print_r(get_categories_h()); exit; ?>`

Comment: Please post your full modal `Product_model.php` code.

Comment: Ok i edited my question and it now shows all the code in Product.model file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153947/discussion-between-nikunj-rathod-and-lablanco).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a model from a helper you can code in the function in the helper itsef and return the result to the view file. Plus you need to add the helper in the autoupload.php file in the cofig directory.

```
 function get_categories(){
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->db->select('*');
        $ci->db->from('categories');
        $q= $ci->db->get()->result();
        return $q;
    }
```

Comment: Hello sir I coped your code and put it in my model and I added the helper in the autoload.php file and I'm getting this error now: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 27

Backtrace:

Comment: ```$ci->db->get()->result();``` Error is because of this line. replace result with ```$ci->db->get()->result_array();```

Comment: So you are actually returning an array and using that array as an object. in your view file:
$category->name;

Comment: instead of this use $category['name'];

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: q

Filename: models/Product_model.php

Line Number: 42

Comment: Filename: models/Product_model.php Line Number: 42
Function created by me is for helper not for a model file as i am using $ci so kindly add this function in the helper file and call this function from the view file directly.